# Sorting a list as the output of the collect on JavaRDD

Tags: java, apache-spark

I am collecting an RDD and need to sort it in Spark Java API, using the following code:

```
List<Long> alarmedTimeStamps=sensorDataDoubleDF.toJavaRDD().filter(filterAlarmNode).filter(filterAlarmInstances).map(row->row.getLong(2)).collect();
System.out.println("The type of collection is :"+alarmedTimeStamps.getClass().getTypeName());


ArrayList<Long> javaAlarmedTimeStamps=new ArrayList();
for(Long item:alarmedTimeStamps)
    javaAlarmedTimeStamps.add(item);

//sort the TTS points
Collections.sort(javaAlarmedTimeStamps);
```

The type of collection is :scala.collection.convert.Wrappers$SeqWrapper

I am using a manual conversion in this code, but I wonder if there is any better way.

Comment: Have your tried sorting your data before you call the collect function?

Comment: well, no, I have also edited my question.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are looking for the [`sortBy`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/java/index.html?org/apache/spark/api/java/JavaRDD.html) method.

Your code could be transformed to:

```
List<Long> javaAlarmedTimeStamps = sensorDataDoubleDF
.toJavaRDD()
.filter(filterAlarmNode)
.filter(filterAlarmInstances)
.map(row->row.getLong(2))
.sortBy(x->x,true,1) //you could also replace the previous `map` with sortBy(row->row.getLong(2),true,1)
.collect();
```

By the way, in your code, the reason you cannot sort directly `alarmedTimeStamps` is because it is [immutable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/immutable.html). However, you can initialize your copy of `alarmedTimeStamps`, called `javaAlarmedTimeStamps`, more easily than you do:

```
List<Long> javaAlarmedTimeStamps = new ArrayList<>(alarmedTimeStamps);
```

Comment: @Luckylukee you are welcome. you can mark answers as accepted by cliking on the tick mark next to them (also applies to the rest of your questions).